# Using MATCH function to pull out index of last non-zero cell in a row

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have a row with cells of the following format.

[image]

I would like a formula which would pull out the index of the last non-zero cell. E.g. I1.

I have the following formula:

`=INDEX(A1:N1<>0,0)`

This seems to work for a number of my examples for other will just return the length of the row.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the *index* of the last value you can use...

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:N1<>0),COLUMN(A1:N1))
```

To return the *value* of the last found non-zero (index) you can combine with INDEX to become...

```
=INDEX(A1:N1,,LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:N1<>0),COLUMN(A1:N1)))
```

Comment: It's good, but according to to this https://exceljet.net/formula/get-value-of-last-non-empty-cell you don't have to use index to get the value, could have just put =LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:N1<>0),A1:N1)